# Localization not working on device

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I localized my app in french, created Localizable.strings with appropriate translations, as well for the storyboard.
When I run the app on the french device, storyboard labels are translated correctly, but not the ones coming from Localizable.strings.

I printed preferredLanguages() and NSLocaleLanguageCode and they are correct on the device ("fr").

If I force the language "fr" with the Edit Scheme, it works, but if I go back to "System Language", it does not work anymore.

Reading other posts, I also cleaned, delete app from device, reset content and settings on the simulator, relaunch Xcode, ...

I can't see why the app does not use the language defined on the device for the Localizable.Strings !

Thanks for your help...

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but it might help someone if you listed the OS / Xcode versions in your question.

Comment: I use Xcode 7.01 (Swift 2) under El Capitan, and iOS 9 on an iPhone 6.